# Use library to do HttpPost + Parse Json Data

Tags: android, mysql, json

I have an Android app communicating with an external MySQL Database. I can do my operations without any problem, but each query generates a lot of code, ( HTTPost + Json Parsing) and I have a lot of queries.

Is there a way to factorise code, a good lib, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is AsyncHttpClient:  http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
where you get `onSuccess` and `onFailure` methods to work with the response.

**To parse your data:**
As your response is `JSON` format, you may be better off using `Gson` library to map data and with custom model classes. Eg.:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ModelClass modelClass= new ModelClass();
    modelClass= gson.fromJson(responseContent,ModelClass.class); 
//where responseContent is your jsonString
    Log.i("Web service response", ""+modelClass.toString());
```

More on: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

For Naming discrepancies(according to the variables in webservice), can use annotations like 
`@SerializedName`.

Use a for each loop  to verify/browse/access the data that would be populated in/as objects/fields of your model class:
Check these for doubts:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html
[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)